# C#: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, .net, mono, xamarin.ios

I have code as follows:

```
Dictionary<object, object> dict = ...
Color = (int)dict.GetValue("color");
```

When I convert the Color to an int, I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Int64' to type 'System.Int32'.

I am not sure why I can't just cast from a long to an int. I know for a fact that the value is less than `0xFFFFFF` (24 bits) since it is a color.

I tried using `unchecked` but that didn't help either.

Comment: Error is what error is, although it is a bit confusing because `(x)expr` is either a *cast* or a *conversion* depending on the expression type. The correction would be `(int)(long)dict.GetValue("color")` which corresponds to `(conversion)((cast)obj)`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You must first [unbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) the value as the dictionary's value type is `object`.

```
Dictionary<object, object> dict = ...
Color = (int)(long)dict.GetValue("color");
```

Answer (score 17):

If you don't know the original type, the following idiom may be more convenient.

```
public T Get<T>(string key)
{
    return (T) Convert.ChangeType(_dict[key], typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```