# How to get the average of a column in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the average of a column (as a double/float or decimal). I've found the `AVG` function in MySQL documentation but I can't get it to work. Currently I've got the following code:

```
public double GetRating(string username)
        {
            double average;

            MySqlConnection databaseConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            string sumQuery = "select sum('rating') from " + username;
            string countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + username;
            using (MySqlCommand sumCommand = new MySqlCommand(sumQuery, databaseConnection))
            using (MySqlCommand countCommand = new MySqlCommand(countQuery, databaseConnection))

            try
            {
                databaseConnection.Open();
                
                double sum = (Double)sumCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                double columnLength = (Double)countCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                average = sum / columnLength;
                return average;
             }

            finally
            {
                databaseConnection.Close();
            }

            return average;
        }
```

Now for some reason this does not work. It returns "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Double'."

The stored data in the database is an int but i'm trying to cast them to double. Any suggestions or solutions? Once again; double/float or decimal are usable for me.

Comment: you can use `AVG` function instead of calculating the sum and counting the rows and dividing the values.

Comment: I have tried using the AVG function, but I could not get it to work... Do you think you can provide me with an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31737978/9978223

Comment: Wait: you have a different table for each username? Why would you do that? Also you can return multiple results from a single `SELECT` using `ExecuteReader`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `AVG` function (an aggregate function) could be used like so:

```
select avg(rating) from table_name
```

Note that, like most aggregate functions, the average will exclude null values (the average of `1, 2, null` is 1.5 instead of 1.0). Also, in MySQL the return datatype will be `decimal` if you're averaging decimal or integer columns so use the appropriate C# datatype.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know it would return a decimal. Now it works

Comment: Actually count returns an integer but sum returns integer, decimal or float depending on column. That was the problem in your original code.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. What is the data type of the `rating` column in the table? If it is an integer and not floating-point, please change the data type of `sum` accordingly to avoid the type-cast error.
2. As you already know, you may use avg() instead of sum() and then division by `count()`. Your SQL will look like:

```sql
select avg(rating) from table_name
```

Comment: (a) `avg('rating')` will calculate the average of a ***string literal*** which does not make sense. Corrected the code (b) unlike sql server, the average returns decimal for integer columns instead of integer so datatype does not need to be changed.

Comment: The quotation was a typo and can be avoided. Modified.